# How to reload page and when finished move to next page

Tags: php

I am building a recipe app and part of my "add_recipe" process is 3 pages. The first one adds major details.

My second page allows a user to add an ingredient to the recipe by entering info and clicking a button. When they are finished adding all the ingredients they want, they have a second button to click that adds all the ingredients to the recipe in the table and moves to the 3rd page.

Next I want to take them to a page where they can add instructions for cooking the recipe. I duplicated the process for adding ingredients (they can continue to add instructions using the first button, or add the instructions to the table by clicking the second button).

Here are the issues I am running into:

Using the following code, I can do the following:

A. continue to add ingredients, and then go to the recipe page on the second button click without going to instructions:

```
if ((empty($title) || empty($subtitle)) && !isset($_POST['ingredient'])){
    include 'inc/add-recipe.php';
}else {
    //Load Ingredient form until all ingredients added
    include 'inc/add-ingredient.php';
}
```

B. user is allowed to enter one ingredient, then it forces them to the 3rd page

```
if ((empty($title) || empty($subtitle)) && !isset($_POST['ingredient'])){
    include 'inc/add-recipe.php';
}elseif (!isset($_POST['ingredient'])){
    //Load Ingredient form until all ingredients added
    include 'inc/add-ingredient.php';
}else{
    include 'inc/add-instruction.php';
}
```

C. user is forced to 3rd page without allowing them to enter an ingredient

```
if ((empty($title) || empty($subtitle)) && !isset($_POST['ingredient'])){
    include 'inc/add-recipe.php';
}else {
    //Load Ingredient form until all instructions added
    include 'inc/add-instruction.php';
}
```

What I would like to do is allow them to enter as many ingredients as they would like *and then* take them to the 3rd page where they are able to add as many instructions as they would like. Finally, taking them to the new recipe's page.

What part of this code am I getting incorrect? It seems as though the

```
elseif(!isset($_POST['ingredient'])){
}
```

line is incorrect, because it allows them to enter an ingredient, but since it is now set, it jumps right over allowing them to enter a second ingredient.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just have three textboxes on one page? I can just imagine the frustration when you realize you forgot something on page one and have to go back.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? Have a check box for each ingredient added?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use JS and put all in one form

But if you wanna keep it with php there isn't really a way to tell how many ingredients the user wants to add therefore you current logic wont work.

I suggest on the processing scripts

```
<form action="recipe.php?id=<?php echo $recipe_id; ?>" method="post">
```

to assign a currentStatus for each stage.

eg new form the currentStatus = 0;

once add-recipe is completed currentStatus = 1

ingredients completed currentStatus = 2

and so on.

Then on your

```
if ( $currentStatus == false || empty($title) || empty($subtitle)  
{ 
     include 'inc/add-recipe.php';
} 
elseif ( $currentStatus == 1 )
{
      include 'inc/add-ingredient.php'; 

} 
elseif ( $currentStatus == 2 )
{
     include 'inc/add-instruction.php';
}
```

Comment: If I am reading your answer correctly, I should add the lines of code you marked out, to each page? Right now, the snippet I am using is at the bottom of an add.php document. Should I take it out of there and add it individually to the bottom of each page as you described?

Comment: Just place it where u had it before. I didn't change the structure of your code just the logic.

Comment: But as @Andreas said this screams a nightmare for the end-user. I would personally be doing using three textboxes on one page and then using JS or Ajax

Comment: So, I added the code you put in the last example, so that my code looks like that.

Once I add an ingredient, the page goes straight to the instruction page without allowing me to add another ingredient.

Comment: Sorry I see my mistake, Edited.

Comment: That just changed so I go straight to the add-instruction page and jumps right over the ingredient page.

I have a feeling I'm missing something in your response. This comment box does not allow for markup, so I can't put the code. What I have now, is only the 3rd code box you included. Should I be including the 1st and 2nd code boxes somewhere?

Comment: I'm sorry, something changed with your 3rd box. Now I get to enter 1 ingredient and when I click the first box it just jumps straight to the instructions page, when it should clear the boxes and allow me to enter another ingredient.

Comment: Is this all on 1 page??

Comment: Yes. On my add.php, I am including the add-recipe.php content, or the add-ingredient.php content, or the add-instruction.php content. Depending on at what stage the user is in adding information. If they are starting out, then they will see the add-recipe.php. If they have entered the information for the recipe (Title, subtitle, etc.) then the page changes to add-ingredients.php. Here they enter 3 fields for ingredients and either hit a button to add it (refreshing the fields), or a second button to move on to the instructions which then displays the add-instructions.php content.

Comment: Is there a way to include these files so you can see what I am seeing? Maybe this will help with troubleshooting?

Comment: ohh sorry i thought you where using 3 different pages.

Comment: That's my bad. I'm sorry for not clarifying that.

Comment: umm its kinda impossible to know when then are done with ingredients to then move onto instructions. as 1 user may have 1 ingredient or another might have 100.

Comment: can you add a submit button so they click once finished?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 buttons on both the ingredients and instructions pages. There is a "Add [ingredient or instruction]" and a "Finished adding [ingredients or instructions]"

When adding ingredients, in my first code box, I can click the "Add ingredient" button and it will add it. Then, I can add another and another and another. Then when I am done, I click the "Done adding ingredients" button and I am taken to the new recipe's page that shows all the details of the recipe, except the instructions. I can't get the page to load the add-instruction.php content instead of going to the recipe page.

Comment: It's 1am here, so I'm going to go to bed, but I will check on your advice when I get up tomorrow. I really appreciate you taking a look!

Comment: based on your current logic, I cudnt really think of a way to make that work as you will never know when the user has finished with ingredients. Therefore I edited my answer slightly to allow for that.  If you like it please vote and mark it answered otherwise maybe see if someone else might have a better idea. Also let me know and i can help if you need to impermanent it.

Comment: I have a "finished" button so I will know when the user is done editing. This part works.

The problem is going from the add-ingredient.php to add-instruction.php.

Comment: Yeah you will need some sort of button/ action when add-ingredients is done then assign that action and check for it on the add ingredients if and if that has been set then include the instructions.